# Why is a table with two column references to another table not joinable?

Tags: postgresql, join, rust, inner-join, rust-diesel

I have 2 issues.

1. There is no `joinable!` entry for "categories" in the schema.rs, why does this happen?
2. if 2 columns are added with foreign key reference to the same table, it doesn't allow me to add two `joinable!` statements manually , eg:

   ```rust
   joinable!(categories -> users (created_by));
   joinable!(categories -> users (modified_by));
   ```

I tried creating the "categories" table with one foreign key reference to the "users" table, dropped database, deleted schema.rs , ran migration , still no change to the schema.

```rust
table! {
    categories (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        category_code -> Varchar,
        description -> Varchar,
        gl_cr -> Varchar,
        gl_dr -> Varchar,
        asset_cost_less_than -> Nullable<Int4>,
        over_ride_depreciation_rate -> Bool,
        over_ride_useful_life -> Bool,
        created_by -> Int4,
        created_on -> Timestamp,
        modified_by -> Nullable<Int4>,
        modified_date -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
    }
}

table! {
    users (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        username -> Varchar,
        full_name -> Varchar,
        email -> Varchar,
        active -> Bool,
        created_on -> Timestamp,
    }
}
```

part of the schema.rs is

```rust
joinable!(branch_categories -> categories (category_id));
joinable!(branches -> cities (city_id));
joinable!(branches -> users (created_by));
joinable!(category_book_rate_codes -> books (book_id));
joinable!(category_book_rate_codes -> categories (category_id));
joinable!(category_book_rate_codes -> depreciation_rates (rate_id));
joinable!(cities -> states (state_id));
joinable!(cities -> users (created_by));
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Parts of your post that need improvement: title (definitely), description (what library is `table` and `joinable` even from? I guess `diesel`, but that kind of got lost in the chaos of a title), examples (should be minimal, executable and demonstrate your problem), a step-by-step instruction on how to execute your example if it isn't trivial (which I assume, based on your current description)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `categories` table has two columns that reference the `users` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id           INTEGER,
    created_by   INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
    modified_by  INTEGER          REFERENCES users,
    ...
);
```

Diesel will not generate a `joinable!` entry for `categories` to `users` since it would be ambiguous which column to use. You cannot create them both manually either because their implementations would conflict. The macro is designed to make this kind of query possible without an explicit `ON` clause:

```rust
categories::table.join(users::table)...
```

Not sure why removing one foreign reference and regenerating the schema didn't make a difference for you, but regardless... You can of course implement *one* of them manually like so:

```rust
joinable!(categories -> users (created_by));
```

You could then use the above query syntax when you wanted to join `categories` to `users` based on their creator. If you later want to join them based on their last modifier as well, you can do so in your query explicitly (untested):

```rust
categories::table.join(users::table.on(categories::modified_by.eq(users::id.nullable())))...
```